# Fullpage.js and SlimScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js, slimscroll

I am using the [FullPageJS plugin](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs), and have a question regarding it. I have multiple sections, and in some sections the content overflows the browser's height.

When this occurs I have used the [jQuery.slimScroll plugin](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll) as suggested by the documentation to cater for the overflowing content. This places a nice scrollbar within the section for the user to access the overflowing content. This works like a charm.

Once a user scrolls down within this section, and then moves on to different section, the slimScroll plugin doesn't reset to the top of the section with the overflowing content.

Can this resetting be achieved, and if so how?

If my question is ambiguous, please ask for clarification and I'll try to clear it up.

Cheers.

Comment: The plugin doesn't provide any option for it. You'll have to do it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks - I figured as much, as I have gone through the documentation closely. Can you point me in the direction where I can achieve this? I've tried to use the jQuery.slimScroll API directly but again with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

add the folowing line to your Script

```
paddingTop: 70,
```

See example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2dhkR/